# Sending Post Request to a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services

I have this php code.

```
<?php  
       $users = $this->Session->read("user");
       $varFName = $users['User']['first_name'];
       $varLName = $users['User']['last_name'];
       $message = "Hello,
 I would like to invite you to Clicksays! ".$varFName." ".$varLName;
       echo $this->Form->create('User', array('id' => 'sendEmailRequest', 'style'=>'padding : 0px;', 'url' => array('controller' => 'Contacts', 'action' => 'addEmailRequest')));
       echo $this->Form->input('Email', array('id' => 'email', "size"=>"40"));
       echo $this->Form->textarea("Message", array("type"=>"textarea", "id"=>"PreviewEmail", "style"=>"display:none;","rows"=>"5", "cols"=>"45", "value"=>$message));
       echo $this->Form->button('Preview and edit invitation Clickup', array("id" => "butInvite", "type"=>"button"));
       echo $this->Form->button('Send invitation Clickup', array('id' => 'butSendInvitation',  'type'=>'submit'));
       echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Now it accepts the array of data for user,email and message:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myLink"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:6.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

Now I am pretty sure I need to put the array as the HTTP body, but I don't know how. I am not a web guy, and know little about the web programming and the methods.

How can I pass the details? It does not work without it, and post the error to enter the details for the user, that code exist in php too.

Comment: If u want to sent as an array u should be sending as a Json string. U can convert an array into Json string using NSJsonSerialisation class

Comment: try posting an answer..if it helps me ..i will accept as well +1 to you..by the way..i need ios4.0 compatibility..

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    NSString *urlString = @"Your url";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];




    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    // Text parameter1
    // NSString *param1 = @"parameter text";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:param1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    // Another text parameter
    // NSString *param2 = @"Parameter 2 text";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:param2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

like above code u can send the multiple value using HTTP post method.